# Overloading << to output into a file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ofstream

So I have:

in my .h:

```
friend std::ofstream & operator <<(std::ofstream & output, myClass & s);
```

and in my .cpp

```
 std::ofstream & operator <<(std::ofstream & output, myClass & s)
{
    ofstream ofile << ("output.txt");
    output << "Test" << endl;
    return output;
}
```

I get errors:

> expected initializer before '<<' token

at `std::ofstream & operator <<(std::ofstream & output, myClass & s)

and

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}' and 'const char [5]')

at `ofstream ofile << ("output.txt");`

Whats the poblem?`

`

Comment: The line `ofstream ofile << ("output.txt");` is both incorrect and unnecessary. You should remove it.

Comment: So how do I create an output.txt file?

Comment: @user3452963 Outside the operator, as usual: `myClass c; std::ofstream s("output.txt"); s << c;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to restrict a function to `std::ofstream` when it may as well work with *any* kind of `std::ostream`. It also looks highly suspicious when you pass a non-`const` reference to a print function. This means that you officially allow printing to have side effects which *modify* the printed object!

For those reasons, you should change this:

> ```
> std::ofstream & operator <<(std::ofstream & output, myClass & s);
> ```

To this:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & output, myClass const& s);
```

You don't need to create a stream instance in the implementation of the operator, either. You receive a reference to one as the first argument. So just do this (and while we're at it, avoid `endl` unless you know exactly what you are doing):

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & output, myClass const& s);
{
    output << "Test\n";
    // output << s.some_member << "\n";
    return output;
}
```

You can now just pass an `std::ofstream` object to that function and will write into the file. You just need to create the object, passing the filename to its constructor:

```
myClass s;
std::ofstream os("output.txt");
os << s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something similar to the following:

```
ofstream ofile{"output.txt"};
ofile << some_object;
```

This is the calling of the constructor of *std::ofstream* and the subsequent writing to the specified stream which in turn writes to the file.